# SQLite: combination of different ordering policies in one query

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a table which holds 4 columns: *int x, int y, int z, int type*.

I need to select sorted list of records when next properties preserved:

All records with **type 1** must be ordered by **x** and **y** (**y** is secondary key) in ascending order;

All records of **type 2** must be ordered by **z**. In ascending order.
Records of **type 2** usually ordered by **x** and **y** and when ordered by **z** the ordering should be the same. In theory. However, in reality some of **type 2** records may be partially disordered with respect to **z**, i.e. for them table.x2 > table.x1 but table.z2 < table.z1.

I need for all selected records of type 2 to ensure table.z2 > table.z1 even at price of having table.x1 > table.x2 (implied, that table.x1 < table.x2 for all other records).

I figured out some query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM aTable ORDER BY CASE type WHEN 1 THEN x ASC, y ASC ELSE z ASC END;
```

but for some reason SQLite rejects it as syntactically wrong.

Is it possible anyway to construct such query?

**UPDATE:**
Example

Data in table

x y z type

1 4 3 1

2 3 6 1

2 2 6 1

8 3 5 2

4 6 3 2

5 8 6 1

7 6 2 2

Expected result:

1 4 3 1

2 2 6 1

2 3 6 1

7 6 2 2

4 6 3 2

5 8 6 1

8 3 5 2

Comment: You could clarify what you want with sample data and expected results covering all the edge cases of your requirement.

Comment: Can you explain why you want the row `5 8 6 1` before the row `8 3 5 2` in your expected results?

Comment: This is requirement.

Comment: Is there any logic behind this so that it can be applied to the ORDER BY clause?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. There is other piece of software that consumes that list. It should not modify the list in any way, so the proper ordering from the start is important.

Comment: The proper ordering is defined by conditions. The conditions that you mention in your question do not cover the case of the rows `5 8 6 1` and `8 3 5 2` which have different types. In the original table the row `8 3 5 2` is placed *before* the row `5 8 6 1`. In your expected results you want `5 8 6 1` *before* `8 3 5 2`. Why? Which condition should be applied here?

Comment: I m not sure. Probably the condition should be : for all records of type 1 sort by x,y; for all recs of type 2 sort by z,x,y.

Comment: This would work if you select only rows with type = 1 or only rows with type = 2. If you want all the rows of the table there should also be a condition that defines uniquely what happens when both types exist in the resultset. As I mention in my previous comments I don't see any reason for the rows `5 8 6 1` and `8 3 5 2` to be returned in the order that you show in your expected results.